# Reuse function to delete an item

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I want to make a button that adds and removes items.
The 'Delete form' button changes to 'Add form' after click it.
But after I've deleted and added forms, I want to delete forms again, but for reasons I don't understand, it doesn't happen.

I'm using the latest chrome browser version.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" style="height: 100%">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <title>Task 1</title>
</head>
<body style="height: 100%">
    <div class="container h-100">
        <div class="row h-100 justify-content-center align-content-center">
            <div class=""><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Open Google</button></div>
            <div class=""><button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" id="danger">Delete form</button></div>
            <div class="breaker w-100" style="height:10%;"></div>
            <form id="form"> 
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="formGroupExampleInput">Example label</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="formGroupExampleInput" placeholder="Example input">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="formGroupExampleInput2">Another label</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="formGroupExampleInput2" placeholder="Another input">
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>  
    <script src="./index.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

```
document.getElementsByClassName('btn-primary')[0].addEventListener("click", open_google);
document.getElementsByClassName('btn-danger')[0].addEventListener("click", delete_function);

let inner_form = document.getElementById('form').innerHTML;

function open_google() {
    window.open('http://google.com', '_blank');
}

let buttons;

function button_change(button) {
    switch(button) {
        case "success":
            buttons = document.getElementsByClassName('btn');
            buttons[1].innerHTML = 'Add form';
            buttons[1].className = 'btn btn-success';
            document.getElementsByClassName('btn-success')[0].addEventListener("click", add_function);
            break;
        case "danger":
            buttons = document.getElementsByClassName('btn');
            buttons[1].innerHTML = 'Delete form';
            buttons[1].className = 'btn btn-danger';
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}

function delete_function() {
    let element = document.getElementById('form');
    while (element.firstChild) {
      element.removeChild(element.firstChild);
    }
    button_change("success");
}

function add_function() {
    document.getElementById('form').innerHTML = inner_form;
    button_change("danger");
}
```

Example code: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/xNjPYj

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The event listeners aren't being removed, so *both* functions are being called (potentially multiple times) depending on how many times the buttons are clicked.

Personally, I think it would be easier to create two buttons, each with independent click handlers, and hide/show them according to which one was clicked.

However, to resolve the current issue in your code, you'll need to remove the previous event listener using [removeEventListener()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/removeEventListener) before attaching the new one.

Comment: Really, I get it now.
I didn't think it was the same element at all.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just hide it? This is much easier

```js
    function toggle() {
     var element = document.getElementById("form");
      if (element.style.display === "none") {
        element.style.display = "block";
      } 
      else {
        element.style.display = "none";
      }
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" style="height: 100%">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    

    <title>Task 1</title>
</head>
<body style="height: 100%">
    <div class="container h-100">
        <div class="row h-100 justify-content-center align-content-center">
            <div class=""><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Open Google</button></div>
            <div class=""><button onclick="toggle()" type="button" class="btn btn-danger" id="danger">Delete form</button></div>
            <div class="breaker w-100" style="height:10%;"></div>
            <form id="form"> 
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="formGroupExampleInput">Example label</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="formGroupExampleInput" placeholder="Example input">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="formGroupExampleInput2">Another label</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="formGroupExampleInput2" placeholder="Another input">
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>  
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @AbdulkhayKhabibulin why would you make it difficult if it can be easy

Comment: I'll make it as simple as possible when I know more.

Answer (score 0):

The main issue with your code was that the event listeners kept getting added but not removed, this caused them to pile up and run unpredictably. I added a function that determines what state the button is in and performs the correct function `add_function` or `remove_function`.

I also changed a few minor things

- Now uses`innerHTML` to `textContent` where possible for security
- Button classes are updated using `button.classList.add` and `button.classList.remove`
- The button is found using an ID instead of an unreliable classname
- The button is held in a variable instead of continuing the look for it
- Removed the `button_change` function because it was difficult to refactor

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/BexJZW

JavaScript:

```
document.getElementsByClassName('btn-primary')[0].addEventListener("click", open_google);

let inner_form = document.getElementById('form').innerHTML;

let add_delete_button = document.querySelector('#add-delete-button');
add_delete_button.addEventListener("click", on_add_delete_clicked);

function open_google() {
    window.open('http://google.com', '_blank');
}

function on_add_delete_clicked() {
    let is_adding = add_delete_button.classList.contains("btn-success");
    if (is_adding) {
        add_function();
    } else {
        delete_function();
    }
}

function add_function() {
    const button = add_delete_button;
    document.getElementById('form').innerHTML = inner_form;

    // Update button
    button.textContent = 'Delete form';
    button.classList.remove("btn-success");
    button.classList.add("btn-danger");
}

function delete_function() {
    let element = document.getElementById('form');
    while (element.firstChild) {
        element.removeChild(element.firstChild);
    }

    // Update button
    const button = add_delete_button;
    button.textContent = 'Add form';
    button.classList.remove("btn-danger");
    button.classList.add("btn-success");
}
```

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" style="height: 100%">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

  <title>Task 1</title>
</head>
<body style="height: 100%">
    <div class="container h-100">
        <div class="row h-100 justify-content-center align-content-center">
            <div class=""><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Open Google</button></div>
            <div class=""><button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" id="add-delete-button">Delete form</button></div>
            <div class="breaker w-100" style="height:10%;"></div>
            <form id="form"> 
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="formGroupExampleInput">Example label</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="formGroupExampleInput" placeholder="Example input">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="formGroupExampleInput2">Another label</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="formGroupExampleInput2" placeholder="Another input">
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>  
    <script src="./index.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It's a good decision, I've studied and tried it.
But the functions of adding and removing also perform the updating of the button, shouldn't it be in a separate function?

Answer (score 0):

This implementation will do the text and context switching you desire.

```
function action(mouseevent) {
  const button = mouseevent.target;
  let element = document.getElementById('form');
  if(element.firstChild) {
    while (element.firstChild) {
      element.removeChild(element.firstChild);
    }
    button.innerHTML = 'Add form';
    button.classList.remove('btn-danger');
    button.classList.add('btn-success');
  } else {
    document.getElementById('form').innerHTML = inner_form;
    button.innerHTML = 'Delete Form';
    button.classList.add('btn-danger');
    button.classList.remove('btn-success');
  }      
}
```